# Is the participle clause in “the marlin left a blood trail attracting sharks” correct?

Tags: grammaticality, participles

I'm writing a summary of the novel "The old man and the sea". And I'm trying to use participle clauses (a subject that I'm currently learning).

I've learnt that you can use a participle clause to describe an action that is the result of another action, so I wrote:

> *Then, having succeeded in his catch and taking his way back. He faced another problem: the marlin left a blood trail **attracting sharks**.*

Is the second sentence correct?  Meaning: *"The marlin left a blood trail **which attracted sharks**"*

Also, Doesn't the word *"then"* in the first sentence sound redundant?

> *"Then, having succeeded..."*

In the original sentence would be *"Then, after he have succeeded"*

Comment: Is correct the participle clause in the example sentence. However, is not correct the question.

Comment: Yes. But it's still ungrammatical. Questions are much simpler than participle clauses, grammatically; perhaps you ought to pay more attention to the basics before attempting the complex parts.

Comment: I don't understand,  what's wrong with the question?

Comment: Ah, now it's been edited again. That one is correct. Congratulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the participle clause in “the marlin left a blood trail attracting sharks” correct?

There's no grammatical problems with "attracting sharks".

There are a couple of grammatical problems in the larger text, "Then, having succeeded in his catch and taking his way back. He faced another problem: the marlin left a blood trail attracting sharks."

First, "taking" should be "making".
Second, there is a sentence fragment starting with "Then" and ending with "back".

You could correct this text to: "Then, having succeeded in his catch and making his way back, he faced another problem: the marlin left a blood trail attracting sharks."

The word "Then" is not necessary but it could be a useful transition word depending on the prior sentences.  If nearly every sentence begins with "then" then that's not a well written summary, but if the "then" is used occasionally it can be effective.

Finally, I'm not sure it's completely accurate that the fish immediately leaves a trail of blood.  I recall the first shark catches the scent of the dead marlin and follows the trail of that scent, but that's a little different image than a trail of blood.  Therefore there seems to be an inaccuracy in your description, though not in grammar at that point.

Comment: Thank you! I've made the corrections though I've still struggle with the basics ('cause in my head I'm thinking in my native language and it sounds ok).

Accordingly to what you wrote, I'm fine with the use of the word "Then" 'cause it is the only time that I've used the word in that way.

And for the last part, I think we are both right. The shark realized the blood first, then he followed the scent.

“He had come up from deep down in the water as the dark cloud of blood had settled and dispersed in the mile deep sea.”

Comment: If you could identify your native language it would help. This is true for just about everybody on ELU, by the way -- in person we could probly tell by your accent right away, but writing disguises accent along with many other language features.

Comment: Spanish is my native language. :]